# Updating Excel sheet cell (the cell is a dropdown list)

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

Basically I have a template excel sheet that I copy to another directory.
I open the connection to said new sheet using:

```vb
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" &  excel_copy & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;"""
Set rsHoja = cn.OpenSchema(20)
hoja=rsHoja("Table_Name")
rsHoja.close
Set rsHoja = nothing  
Set rsHoja = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

From This point on I've been successfully doing updates such as:

```vb
sql =  " UPDATE [Hoja1$B2:B2] SET F1='"&VALUE&"'"
rsHoja.Open sql, cn
```

The problem comes when I'm trying to do an update on a cell that takes it's value from a List(that is in the same sheet)

I keep getting an error:

```
Microsoft Access Database Engine error '80040e10'
```

Any idea how to assign the value to the cell from the List? I've tried the list's name[cell of the value] and other methods but I'm pretty much trying to figure it out blindly now.
I've also looked everywhere with no luck.

Update 1:

I forgot to mention my file doesn't have headers if that's any help.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finally found the problem...It had nohing to do do with my SQL or the cell having a list,the problem was that the cell was marked(in the excel sheet) as a DATE but the List was a String so whenever I tried to write my string on it gave the type error...changing the cell on the excel to string/general fixed the issue,the cell gets the value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0** database engine for connection,

Possibilities:

1) Make sure you are using **Excel 12.0** in **Extended Properties**  if you are using **.xlsx** file as Data source

2) Make sure you are using **Excel 8.0** in **Extended Properties** if you are using **.xls** file as Data source

Check this URL for more info on this:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply, I'm using .xlsm files, I checked for the connection string and changed the "Excel 8.0" to "12.0" but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Is your sheet Name "[Hoja1$B2:B2]" ?? Mention only sheet name there. It should be more like this : Update [Sheet1$] Set [ColumnName] = "updatedvalue" Where [RowID] = rowvalue.

Comment: My sheet name is "Hoja1" , can i use [ColumnName]  when I don't have headers?Or column name is [Hoja1$B2:B2] ?.

Comment: keep column name as F1, what you have kept in original code. But just use sheet name as [Hoja1$]

Comment: @MikaelMadrid In that case post an answer so you can accept it and this question will no longer float around on the unanswered list.